# How do I show that a function is one-to-one, maps onto, and it inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help with this question.

Consider the function $f:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ defined by

$$f(x,y) = (2x+y,x-2y)$$

a)Prove that $f$ is one-to-one on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$

do I input values of different $x$ and $y$ to prove that it works?

b)Prove that $f$ maps $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$

What does it mean to map onto?

c) Find the inverse function of $f$

How do I find the inverse of such functions?

Comment: You need **first** to know the meaning of things. Go and google "injective" or "one-to-one" or "1-1" mappings, and "surjective" or "onto" mappings. Otherwise you are not asking for help but for someone to do your work.

Comment: Why don't you just compute the Jacobian?

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

(1) Show that $\;(2x+y, x-2y)=(2x'+y',x'-2y')\iff x=x'\;,\;\;y=y'\;$

(2) Show that for any $\;(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2\;$ there exist $\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ s.t. $\;(2x+y,x-2y)=(a,b)\;$

Answer (score 1):

(a) Rewrite $f$ as,

$$f\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 &1 \\ 
 1&-2 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Notice the matrix is exactly the Jacobian of $f$ and as it is clearly non-singular, by Inverse Function Theorem (you actually don't need this as this matrix is very simple), it must also be one to one.

(b) The determinant of the Jacobian found in (a) has a nonzero determinant, so the columns span $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore this is onto.

Onto means that for every point in the "target space", you can always find a point in your domain that maps to that point in the target space.

(c) Let $$J = \begin{bmatrix}
2 &1 \\ 
 1&-2 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Note that

$$JJ^{-1} = I.$$

So the inverse of $J$ is given by

$$J^{-1} = \frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix}
2 &1 \\ 
 1&-2 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Hence $$g(x,y) = \frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix}
2 &1 \\ 
 1&-2 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: "The Jacobian of $\;f\;$" ? I don't think (1) multivariable calculus has a business here, though it can be an interesting approach, yet (2) the basic level of the question makes it highly unlikely the OP has reached this point in his studies...

Comment: I'll erase the comments and make it strictly linear-algebra based.

Comment: No need, @nameless (in particular because it may be the OP is a budding linear algebra student, so basic stuff as a linear map with finite dimensional spaces as domain is injective iff its kernel is zero and stuff can *also* be beyond his reach). Perhaps only some warning about the approach, which can be useful for others...

Comment: Your approaches are nice and I think they can be helpful. +1

Comment: Oh I wish there was a rollback for answers...

Comment: There is, and you can do it easily: enter into "editing" and rollback...:)

Comment: Oh it was on top, I didn't see that. Thanks